# ¿Cómo centro un encabezado?

Tags: html

Quiero centrar el encabezado de mi página con el atributo `<p aling=center> </p>`, pero no funciona :(

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Este es mi código hasta ahora (Me falta mucho por delante, pero así voy)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title> My first web page</title>
    
</head>    
<body>
    <div> <p aling=center>
        <h3>Welcome to my first web page </h3>
    </p>
        </div>
    <hr>

     <p>Welcome! this is my firts web page with HTML only code language, Im going to be adding more new things to the page as soon as Im progressing in this wordl of programming </p></h3></body>
     <br/>
     By now I know some elements, like lines, some fast font weight, forms to put a bold font, and line breaks. When I have learned all html, i will start to study CSS, and after that, Javascript and Java, finally, i want to study python.

     <hr/>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes muchas opciones para centrar ese texto, pero no encierres un **h3** dentro de un **p** porque no tiene ningun sentido. **p** es párrafo, y **h** es cabecera. Puedes usar `<center>` en lugar de la `<p>`, puedes usar `<h3 style="text-align:center">` sin la `<p>`, etc O bien puedes abrir [este enlace](https://www.google.com/search?q=centrar+texto+html) para más opciones.

Comment: Wow, gracias amigo, si me funcionó, opte por el `<h3 style="text-align:center">` porque asi organizo mejor todo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es mejor no usar la etiqueta `<center>` ([ya es obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)). Mejor dejarle a CSS el trabajo :)

Comment: Por cierto, ¡la palabra es _align_! No olvides además colocar lo que te han puesto como comentario como respuesta, y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.